# chrome devtools background does not run automatically

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I'm building a chrome devtools extension with TypeScript + React

**My Steps**

1. loaded unpacked dist on chrome://extensions
2. open a new tab with devtools page(and the window alerts "this is content script")
3. clicked my extension panel
4. the error appears on chrome://extensions

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.
Context
devtools://devtools/bundled/devtools_app.html?remoteBase=https://chrome-devtools-frontend.appspot.com/serve_file/@a6b12dfad6663f13a7e16e9a42a6a4975374096b/&can_dock=true&dockSide=undocked
Stack Trace
index.html:0 (anonymous function)

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/logo192.png" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />
    <title>React App</title>
    <link href="/static/css/sidebar.2001c5a3.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/static/css/devtools.2001c5a3.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="/static/js/runtime-index.d09d0bdd.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/index.chunk.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/runtime-sidebar.7a085c24.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/0.chunk.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/sidebar.chunk.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/runtime-devtools.f0ac3d91.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/devtools.chunk.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/runtime-background.c42f91dc.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/background.chunk.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/runtime-contentScript.7cf7a071.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/contentScript.chunk.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

But if I click the "inspect views **background page**` manually before step 2, everything works well.

I think the background should start up automatically in production. Did I miss something?

index.tsx

```js
chrome.devtools.panels.create("Garbanzo",
  "favicon.ico",
  "devtools.html",
  function (panel) {
    // code invoked on panel creation
    let backgroundPageConnection: chrome.runtime.Port
    panel.onShown.addListener(function (window) {
      // when the user switches to the panel, check for an elements tab
      // selection
      backgroundPageConnection = chrome.runtime.connect({
        name: "devtools-page"
      });
    });
    panel.onHidden.addListener(function () {
      backgroundPageConnection.disconnect()
    });
  }
);
```

contentScript.chunk.js

```js
alert("this is content script")
```

background.chunk.js

```js
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener((port) => {
    alert("OK");
})
```

manifest.json

```
{
  ...
  "devtools_page": "index.html",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "js": [
        "static/js/content_script.js"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "static/js/background.js"
    ],
    "persistent": true
  },
    "permissions": [
    "storage",
    "declarativeContent",
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
  ],
  ...
}
```

Comment: There's no such thing as "background does not run automatically". The error means some of your messaging code (not shown in the question) is making incorrect assumptions. I can't help further without seeing that code.

Comment: added some details, and thanks for your help

Comment: The code seems perfectly fine so I guess it's a bug in Chrome. I would try rewriting your background script to use `"persistent": false`. However, first I would remove all `alert` calls because it's blocking the entire process so messaging can't respond.

Comment: I tried with false `persistent` and removed all `alert`s, but it still does not work. I tried edge with chromium, and get more warning(in the code area after step 4) which complains anonymous function in index.html:0. Is the problem caused by the template index.html provided by create-react-app ? or something about script permissions?

Comment: You seem to be loading parts(?) of the background script in your devtools page, which is usually wrong because the background script runs in a separate hidden background page, not related to the devtools page.